# Distance function and its approximation

Tags: real-analysis, graph-distance

An easy and quick question:

Consider a function $u\in C(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define a function $Q$ that measures the distance of a point $(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ from the graph of $u$. That is, consider the function
$$Q(x,y)=\inf_{z\in \mathrm{graph}(u)} d_z (x,y)$$

where $d_z(\zeta)=|\zeta - z|$.

My question is:

- why the function $Q$ should be the limit of smooth approximations $Q_p \geq Q$ given by
  $$Q_p(x,y)=\bigg[\int_\Omega \{ d_{(\xi,u(\xi))}(x,y)\}^{-p} \mathrm{d}\xi \bigg]^{-1/p}\quad \textrm{for } (x,y) \notin \mathrm{graph}(u)$$
- why the derivative is
  $$  DQ_p(x,y)=(Q_p(x,y) )^{p+1} \int_\Omega |(x-\xi, y-u(\xi)|^{-p-2}(x-\xi,y-u(\xi))\,\mathrm{d}\xi$$

I just tried to show the uniformly convergence. Can somebody check this following calculation?

Let $d_\xi (x,y) = d_{(\xi,u(\xi))}(x,y)\$. One have

$$d_\xi (x,y) \leq \sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y) \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{d_\xi (x,y) } \geq \dfrac{1}{\sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y)}$$
so applying the integral $$\int_\Omega \bigg( \dfrac{1}{d_\xi (x,y) } \bigg)^p \geq \bigg( \dfrac{1}{\sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y)} \bigg) ^p |\Omega|$$
and so we have
$$ \bigg[\int_\Omega \{ d_{(\xi,u(\xi))}(x,y)\}^{p} \mathrm{d}\xi \bigg]^{1/p}\geq \dfrac{1}{\sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y)} |\Omega|^{1/p}$$
and accordingly
$$\dfrac{1}{\bigg[\int_\Omega \{ d_{(\xi,u(\xi))}(x,y)\}^{p} \mathrm{d}\xi \bigg]^{1/p}} \leq  \dfrac{1}{\bigg( \dfrac{1}{\sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y)} \bigg) |\Omega|^{1/p}} $$
Now to prove the uniformly convergence, one need
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow  \infty } \sup_{(x,y)} | Q_p(x,y) - Q(x,y)| \rightarrow 0$$
By the calculation above, we have
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow  \infty } \sup_{(x,y)} | Q_p(x,y) - Q(x,y)|\leq \lim_{p\rightarrow  \infty } \sup_{(x,y)} \bigg|  \dfrac{1}{\bigg( \dfrac{1}{\sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y)} \bigg) |\Omega|^{1/p}}  - \inf_\xi d_\xi(x,y)\bigg|$$
and using the fact that, in general, $ \dfrac{1}{\sup_x \dfrac{1}{f(x)}} \geq \inf_x f(x)$
follows
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow  \infty } \sup_{(x,y)} | Q_p(x,y) - Q(x,y)|\leq \lim_{p\rightarrow  \infty } \sup_{(x,y)} \bigg| \big(\dfrac{1}{|\Omega|^{1/p}} -1\big) \dfrac{1}{\sup_{\xi} d_\xi (x,y)}\bigg|$$

Now one can put  $\big(\dfrac{1}{|\Omega|^{1/p}} -1\big)$ out of the supremum and calculete the limit for $p\rightarrow \infty$ the result is $0$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

The second identity appears to follow simply from the chain rule applied to
$Q_p(\eta) = f_p(g_p(\eta))$, where
\begin{align*}
f_p(t) &=t^{-1/p},\\
g_p(x,y) &= \int_\Omega \left(d_{(\xi,u(\xi))}(x,y)\right)^{-p}\,\mathrm{d}\xi,\\
d_{(\xi,u(\xi))}(x,y) &= |(x-\xi,y-u(\xi))|
\end{align*}
by definition.

As for the first identity, it looks like $Q_p$ measures the inverse of the distance function $d$ in an $L^p$ norm, and thus the limit $p\to\infty$ should give the supremum norm for this inverse, hence the infimum of the distance itself.

Comment: Thank you @gmvh . I wanted a more formal proof of the first question, for example show that $Q_p(x,y)$ converges uniformly to $ Q(x,y)$...any idea?

Comment: While I believe that "can you check this"-type questions are strongly discouraged on MO, your step-by-step derivation of a more formal statement of what I stated informally looks fine to me (but then I don't know what level of rigour you're aiming for).